# dom4j XML document parsing

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

I have an XML document that I successfully parse into a list of nodes using XPath.

```
Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(bigString));
Node root = documentSelectSingleNode(PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH);
List<Node> productsNodeList = root.selectNodes(PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH + PRODUCTS_PATH);
```

However, when I try to access elements within each node, I don't understand the results. For each node I have the following:

```
System.out.println(node.asXML());
System.out.println("name: " + node.getName());
System.out.println("id: " + node.selectSingleNode("ProductID"));
```

I have also tried "/ProductID" and "//ProductID". In each case, I get xml like the following:

```
<Product xmlns="http://one.two.three/boo/">
  <ProductID>101236026</ProductID>
  <BaseProductName>Widget</BaseProductName>
  <ProductDescription>big widget</ProductDescription>
  <Size>150</Size>
</Product>
```

then

```
name:Product
id: null
```

What is the XPath magic I need to access the ProductID field within the node that I've created?

Comment: What is `PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH` and `PRODUCTS_PATH`? Also  by "I get xml like the following", are you creating the xml or is it the xml that you are using xpath on?

Comment: The line `System.out.println(node.asXML())` prints out xml. It shows the XML on which I'm attempting an XPath expression. I want to get the value for the fields inside this node, such as the field "ProductID". I think I've found the answer, see below.